# E-R modelling and business rules

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

How can I insert in an E-R model a concept like this:
"an user can insert an evalutation of another user who participates to the same event"
where the participation must be deducted from an approved subscription to an event.
I made a recursive relation "Evaluation" from Subscription (which is related to User and to Event) to itself, but I'm not sure it is correct.
Maybe for concepts like this I need to use a business rule?
Thanks.

Comment: ER and other data modeling disciplines are for modeling knowledge, not system capabilities.

Comment: Even if the evaluation must be saved with data, comment and score? Isn't this an entity?

Comment: Now you're on the right track. What are the entities, their attributes, the relationships between them? "A user can insert an evaluation..." indicates system functionality. We now know an evaluation has some "data", a comment and score, and probably involves a scoring user, a scored user and relates to (participation in) an event. What about the other entities? It's not clear what subscription consists of, or what it means to deduct participation from it. Do you perhaps want to model a constraint like "an evaluation's scoring user and scored user must both be participating in the same event"?

Comment: ER diagrams are conceptual models and only represent entities, attributes and relationships. Business rules and constraints can be annotated to a diagram, but not directly represented. When we get to physical modeling, we can use things like foreign key constraints to enforce the validity of the model.

Comment: A subscription to an event is another entity (I suppose) with some attributes: date, role, state (approved/not approved). A special type of user must approve every subscription.
"Do you perhaps want to model a constraint like "an evaluation's scoring user and scored user must both be participating in the same event"?" Exactly!

Comment: @reaanb your description of ER modeling and ER diagrams is strictly correct.  Unfortunately, most of the industry today uses ER diagramming conventions to draw relational schematic diagrams and these go by the name "ER diagrams".  This confuses the distinction between analyzing the subject matter and designing the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example ER diagram:

[image: Evaluation ERD]

We can implement Evaluation and Participation in SQL as:

```
CREATE TABLE Participation (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    EventID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID, EventID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User (UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES Event (EventID)
);

CREATE TABLE Evaluation (
    EvaluationID INT NOT NULL,
    ScoringUserID INT NOT NULL,
    ScoredUserID INT NOT NULL,
    EventID INT NOT NULL,
    Score INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EvaluationID)
);
```

Now, normally we would create foreign key constraints for Evaluation like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Evaluation
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ScoringUserID) REFERENCES User (UserID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ScoredUserID) REFERENCES User (UserID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES Event (EventID);
```

However, in this case a pair of overlapping foreign key constraints referencing Participation will enforce the required business rule:

```
ALTER TABLE Evaluation
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ScoringUserID, EventID) REFERENCES Participation (UserID, EventID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ScoredUserID, EventID) REFERENCES Participation (UserID, EventID);
```

There's some redundancy but it's controlled and required for consistency. Alternatively, it's possible to use triggers to achieve the same effect.

These overlapping FK constraints can't be represented in ER diagrams, though they could be represented logically. In a table diagram, we could draw Crow's foot lines between the tables, but that wouldn't indicate the composite overlapping columns involved.

Comment: Oh...wow! Thank you very much, but I'm a little confuse. I have two types of users: simple users (US) and premium users (UP). UP users WHO CREATED the event must validate every subscription to that specific event. Is this one of the constraints you was talking about, which I can't represent in the ER diagram?
Plus, for every subscription I need to memorize some attributes, like date, state and role (each user can subscript to an event like player or referee).

Comment: You can represent simple/premium users via a suitable attribute on the User entity. You can add a relationship CreatedByUser between Event and User. You can add a Validated attribute (and any other attributes you require) on the Subscription entity. However, enforcing authentication and the process of validation will be a function of your application, not of the database.

Comment: [link](http://oi64.tinypic.com/wjhx1l.jpg)  
This was my elaboration (just a slice). For simplicity I've omitted something. What do you think? I used a recursive relationship (Evaluation).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your project well enough to comment on your model.